# Why does everyone in My Hero Academia care about how Midoriya Izuku got his Quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

They wanted to know because everyone knows that Midoriya was Quirkless, and so does All Might.

But why do they care about Midoriya's Quirk so much? Is it because All Might was Quirkless too when he was Midoriya's age?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. The title seemed missing some words, so I used this chance to [edit] and fixed it according to the question body. If it's wrong, feel free to rollback and improve the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As we find out in Episode 1 of the anime, most people manifest their quirk [by age 4](https://youtu.be/MB8Gq2VZZAw?t=29). It would be uncommon for anyone to manifest their quirk after this, and probably unheard of for a quirk to be manifested as late as high school age (15-16 years).

As a result, when people find out that Midoriya miraculously manifested a quirk at this late age, especially one as powerful as his, they are naturally interested as to what circumstances led to this happening. For most people, it's nothing specific to Midoriya, it's just the circumstances of his quirk. Of course, Bakugo is a lot more obsessed, but that's because of his long history with Midoriya combined with his superiority complex.

### **Edit**

As pointed out by @TheGamer007 in the comments, there might actually not be a lot of people that know Midoriya was previously quirkless.

> TheGamer007: ...in hindsight, the attention focused on Midoriya could be because normal quirks aren't as self-destructive as his. I recall someone saying during the Sports Festival arc that "it's like he's just getting used to his quirk".

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but most people do not know he's Quirkless right? Bakugo is the only one who knew him before UA, and while he mentions that Midoriya should be quirkless during the arc where Eraserhead makes the class take tests for the first time, nothing much came out of that. Other characters are often interested by the similarity to All Might's quirk, and they don't seem to know or care about his quirkless past.

Comment: @TheGamer007 very good point. I'll see if I can rework my answer with this in mind.

Comment: The answer is pretty great considering the question itself assumed "everyone knows he was Quirkless". Plus, none of the characters apart from Midoriya, All Might, Nana Shimura, and possibly Gran Torino, should be knowing that All Might was quirkless at the start. And in hindsight, the attention focused on Midoriya could be because normal quirks aren't as self-destructive as his. I recall someone saying during the Sports Festival arc that "it's like he's just getting used to his quirk".

Answer (score 0):

Well everyone cares about Midoria's quirk because any naturally developed quirk would not cause that much damage to his user so it's possible that everyone has their own doubt about his quirk and in the starting episodes when Bokugo found out that Midoria used his quirk to pass the exam he tells everyone that he was quirkless when he was a kid even if they don't believe it but this two reason's are enough to trigger their curiosity.